# css issue in dynamic content injected by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, stylesheet

Hi I have a chrome extension that is injecting/appending some dynamic divs in website. 
The styling for divs is working fine when locally testing without chrome extension. But when those divs appended to website through chrome extension, my divs got some style from website. And my div didn't look like they are with the original style.
How I can avoid website to not disturb the styles of my dynamic injected/appended contents?

Answer (score 0):

Simply either change your classes or ids, or remove that chrome extension.